# Microsoft ACCESS database record field not whats shown

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Working with a MS ACCESS 2010 accdb file. Within a table, on one particular record, I am experiencing something odd with a text field.

The text field is shown to be populated with Gzzzzzz. However, clicking on the fields [down arrow], [Text Filters], [Equals...] and pasting Gzzzzzz returns nothing. Then, clicking on the fields [down arrow], the shown field populations include GzzzzzzGzzzzzz: not, Gzzzzzz. Selecting GzzzzzzGzzzzzz a record is returned with the field populated with Gzzzzzz.

Showing all the fields again, and editing the field to Azzzzzz. Then, filtering on Azzzzzz again returns nothing. Then, filtering field options show AzzzzzzGzzzzzz: which when selected, returns Azzzzzz.

Also curious, when I filtered as above then look at the Property sheet, at this point the Filter shown is ([TableName].[FieldName] = "Azzzzzz ...missing the final "). However, when I filter on a working record, the Filter is shown as ([TableName].[FieldName] = "Whatever"): meaning shown completely with the trailing ").

The field is not indexed. There are no defaults or formatting. The table is related to three other tables: but, not on this field and not with Enforce Referential Integrity. Other records in the table are fine and work. Just this record's field.

Does anyone know how this happens? Is there a method to repair the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field in the record probably contains

```
Gzzzzzz
Gzzzzzz
```

(with a newline in there) which isn't easily visible in a single-line textbox.

Use Shift+F2 to open the Zoom window. Or "tab" into the control, so everything is selected. Then delete the whole content and re-enter.

Comment: or drag a line between rows down so the rows are taller (like in Excel).  Then you can see values with multi-line entries

Comment: Thank you Andre and Beth! Seems obvious in hindsight and explains the filter. I should have bridged Excel experiences to recognize this possibility.  Thank you again.